# AWS Spot Instances : At what price am i billed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a small question on the spot pricing. Let us assume I have placed a max bid of $0.15 for a c3.large spot EC2 instance. And the current price at that time time was $0.08per hour.
Eventually in the next hour the spot price dropped to $0.03 per hour. Now my question is at what price will I be charged?

1. $0.08 for the first hour and $0.03 for the second hour?
2. $0.08 for my entire usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation for Spot Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/):

> Spot instance-hours are billed based on the Spot price at the start of
>   each instance-hour. If your Spot Instance is interrupted in the middle
>   of an instance-hour (because the Spot price exceeded your max bid
>   price), you are not billed for that partial hour of Spot use.
>   (However, if you terminate the Spot instance, you are charged for the
>   partial hour of use.)

The important part there is that spot instance-hours are billed based on the Spot price at the start of each instance-hour.

So if the price dropped to $0.03 during the second hour, but not at the time that the second instance-hour began, then you would be charged $0.08 for the second hour. You would be charged $0.03 for the third hour, assuming the price does not change again.